# How NS (NativeScript) render UI?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I'm new to NS.
How NS render UI, eq: If I update text on Label, does NS rerender Label or just update the text.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you update only `text` attribute, only the Label's text is updated.

{N} [Core Module](http://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/), [iOS](https://github.com/NativeScript/ios-runtime), and [Android](https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime) runtime are fully open-source, you may review the code on Github.